# Ruby IO#write_nonblock when to use?

Tags: ruby, io, nonblocking

It's simple for `read_nonblock` since the other end might not send anything yet and we will be blocked until some data is available. But I can't think of a case that `write()` is blocked. Can someone give me an example, sample code is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer... Block if `write()`-ing a huge data that bigger than the system buffer (~2MB?), and the other end is not `recv()`-ing.

Also possible to block when writing to disk if the disk is busy.

*p/s: credit goes to #ruby-lang @freenode :)*